# Getting a SqlClient database record error

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to record from listbox with the following code into a SQL database. But it gives me an error. Here is my code. I show error line the following code.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim baglanti As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dedektor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test1")
Dim adaptor As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim kayit As New DataSet
Dim datakayit As DataRow

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   
    Dim a As Integer
    For a = TextBox1.Text To TextBox2.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add(a)
    Next

      Error line -->  adaptor = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO Table_2([po])VALUES('" + ListBox1.Items.Add(a) + "') ", baglanti)
        adaptor.Fill(kayit, "table_2")

 End Sub
```

Comment: 1.What Error? 2. Use parameterised queries. 3. Concatenating `ListBox1.Items.Add(a)` definitely doesn't look correct semantically in any case. That appears to return an `int` [according to its index in the collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx)

Comment: Yikes. **NEVER** use string concatenation like this to put data into a an SQL query. It's the fastest way I know to get your app hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick Recap.

```
    Dim sqlquery As String = ""INSERT INTO Table_2([po])VALUES(@po)" //sql string
    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlquery, con) //Insert             

    Dim a As Integer
    For a = TextBox1.Text To TextBox2.Text   

    cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@po",ListBox1.Items.Add(a)) //use parameters to avoid sql injection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() //execute insert Command

    Next
        //You must call another query to populate your DataSet
        adaptor.Fill(kayit, "table_2")
```

Regards